# Control dateformat when using Url.action or similar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, get, asp.net-mvc-5

I am well aware of the problems with putting dates in the querystring and the way they ignore any globalisation in this instance. I use the standard UK format dd/MM/yyyy in most places in my app - I have the     `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />` set in my web.config, and also use a Custom ModelBinder to make sure even POSTed dates will parse when using the UK format. Having cribbed from [Melvyn Harbour - MVC ModelBinder and Localization](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization)

I have read a number of posts suggesting setting the format to yyyy-MM-dd when passing dates about in the Url, which sounds like a good plan. The problem is how do i set that when i am calling url.action like this:

```
urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, FilteringOptions);
```

where the FilteringOptions is a class with `DateTime` properties within it thus:

```
public class FilteringOptions{
  public string SearchTerm{get;set;}
  public DateTime? FromDate{get;set;}
  public DateTime? ToDate{get;set;}
  public int? BrandID {get;set;}
  //...etc
}
```

I know the last parameter in that Url.Action call above, gets stuck in a  `RouteValueDictionary` and it is here where the `DateTime` properties go wonky, reverting to US date format rather than the UK which is what I had been dealing with - which of course makes it fall over when parsing a date which doesn't work both ways, or almost worse, simply swaps the day and month numbers over causing other mayhem.

I am more than happy to have the dates passed using the yyyy-mm-dd format, **but how do I make sure that format is used**? - without having to loop around all the properties in the class and calling ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") on the date ones.

any help very much appreciated

Comment: A `DateTime` does not have _any_ implicit format. It just have date and time values. A _format_ is only an issue when you try to get their textual representation.

Comment: Hi Soner, I get that - but what am I to do then. I need to have a date passed about in the querystring. I need that in a filtering class in order to do that. how can I pass the date around without it bombing out?

Comment: I've got exactly same problem, MVC is working with GB dates, but calls to Url.Action produces US dates in query string. As far as I investigated RouteValues are going outside MVC scope & are processed by System.Web, that doesn't respect your culture. The only solution so far is instead of passing your model, pass anonymous type with same properties, just for dates to ToString() - correct dates will end up in query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the system date format, which will make it work perfectly.